# How to call the uniswap execute function from a smart contract? trying to swap tokens for weth at 100% slippage

Tags: solidity, uniswapv3

I'm not a developer / have dev background.

I was trying to swap tokens for weth and vice versa in the goerli testnet on uniswap and I want to force swap and bypass the UI error for the price impact.

The function I'm looking to call is the execute function on uniswap which is accessible through the uniswap webUI when you do a regular swap but with a high slippage (90-100%), I have been looking around for 2 days now, asking gpt and googling and reading uniswap universal router documentations, quicknode guides.

Most of the smart contracts GPT wrote me and the guides I tried returned a "transaction might fail" error from metamask, the Liquidity pool of the tokens uses a v2 pool

Does anyone know if there's an suggestions for a working guide or any publicly available dapp / repository that I can utilize to do this?

Thanks in advance